# Strange behavior in for loop, statements not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will show my code and some images to demonstrate the problem.

A simple statement like a variable declaration or using  the log function causes the json result to be undefined. When I type in the text input, the ajax call is executed and returns the data.

**updated** Here is my code included as text. When copy and paste the code the problem of the missing curly braces is very clear. As you can see in the pictures VS 2017 doesn't help you notice missing braces easily, they could improve it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)

                   console.log("some message");
               console.log(data[i].titulo);
```

[image]

removing the statement:

[image]

Now check this out, When there's a statement in the for loop it seems that it is evaluated only once.

[image]

When I took the statement the 'i is x' is executed more times.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code in pictures. Better you paste them here further.

Comment: I updated the question with some code I gave it more descriptive title for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to do with the json you using. Purely about the for loop without using curly braces.

You missing the `{}` for your loop. Without {} only the **first statement** is belong to the  `for` loop

So in your case 1, your code is equal to

```
for ( ..) {
 console.log(..);
}
console.log(data[i]...)
```

And it is working in case 2 because you remove the console log statement and hence it is equal to

```
 for ( ..) {
     console.log(data[i]...)
 }
```

If you want to have both statements inside for loop use `{}`

```
for ( ..) {
         console.log(..);
         console.log(data[i]...)
     }
```

Not only to have multiple statements, even for a single statement, try to use {} always just to avoid confusions like this.

Comment: I couldn't see any code ... just pretty pictures :p[

Comment: Days would pass and wouldn't realize this. Thanks!